# How to fetch the data from third party REST API and and display on the page

Tags: javascript, html, javascript-objects, dom-events

I'm new in a programming language.

I want to fetch data from a third-party API (REST) and display data from them to the page.

I need to fetch data from this TVMAZE API and display the data it'has on my site using js.

```
var foo = null;
        fetch('http://api.tvmaze.com/schedule/full')
        .then(resp => resp.json())
        .then(data => foo = data )
        alert("foo value :" + foo);
        var json_data = foo;

var tbl=$("<table/>").attr("id","mytable");
$("#div1").append(tbl);
for(var i=0; i<json_data.length; i++)
{
    var tr="<tr>";
    var td1="<td>"+ json_data[i]["id"]+"</td>";
    var td2="<td>"+ json_data[i]["name"]+"</td>";
    var td3="<td>"+ json_data[i]["image"]+"</td></tr>";
    var td4="<td>"+ json_data[i]["summary"]+"</td></tr>";
    var td5="<td>"+ json_data[i]["airdate"]+"</td></tr>";
    var td6="<td>"+ json_data[i]["airtime"]+"</td></tr>";
    var td7="<td>"+ json_data[i]["airstamp"]+"</td></tr>";
    var td8="<td>"+ json_data[i]["runtime"]+"</td></tr>";
    var td9="<td>"+ json_data[i]["season"]+"</td></tr>";
    var td10="<td>"+ json_data[i]["language"]+"</td></tr>";
    var td11="<td>"+ json_data[i]["genres"]+"</td></tr>";
    var td12="<td>"+ json_data[i]["country Name"]+"</td></tr>";
    var td13="<td>"+ json_data[i]["code"]+"</td></tr>";
    var td14="<td>"+ json_data[i]["timezone"]+"</td></tr>";
    var td15="<td>"+ json_data[i]["rating Average"]+"</td></tr>";


   $("#mytable").append(tr+td1+td2+td3+td4+td5+td6+td7+td8+td9+td10+td11+td12+td13+td14+td15); 

}
```

but I'm getting an error while displaying please help me to resolve the issues.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null

Comment: You can user ``localStorage`` to store data in the user's browser to store and then can fetch it anytime.

Comment: Please go read [ask]. Just plain “how to” is not a proper way to ask here on this site.

Comment: var foo = null;
        fetch('http://api.tvmaze.com/schedule/full')
        .then(resp => resp.json())
        .then(data => foo = data )

I'm using this method to fetch the data it's the right way to fetch the data. But now I'm getting an error to display data in html.

Answer (score 0):

```
In html :

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table id="table">
      <tbody id="tbody"><th><td>Id</td><td>Name</td></th></tbody>
    </table>
    <script src="js/my-js.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>

    Javascript : 
     fetch("https://api.github.com/users")
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then(data => {
            console.log(data);
            let tableContainer = document.getElementById("table");
            let tbodyEle = document.getElementById("tbody");
            console.log(tbodyEle);
            for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
              let trEle = document.createElement("tr");
              let tdEle = document.createElement("td");
              let td2Ele = document.createElement("td");
              let pEle = document.createTextNode("p");
              pEle = document.createTextNode(data[i].id);
              let p2Ele = document.createTextNode("p");
              p2Ele = document.createTextNode(data[i].login);
              tdEle.append(pEle);
              td2Ele.append(p2Ele);
              trEle.append(tdEle);
              trEle.append(td2Ele);
              tbodyEle.append(trEle);
              tableContainer.append(tbodyEle);
            }
          });
```

Answer (score 0):

json_data is coming null
you must create aync,await call

```
const json_data = async () => 
await (await fetch('http://api.tvmaze.com/schedule/full')).json()
```

and you must check json_data is not null

```
if(json_data != null && json_data.length > 0) 
      //do something
```

Comment: your json_data is a function, not a value. Also async await await isn't very nice.

Comment: thank you for your response but this code not working.

Answer (score 0):

```js
fetch('https://api.tvmaze.com/schedule/full')
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((data) => {
    let html = '<table>'
    data.slice(0, 10).forEach((entry) => {
      html += `<tr><td><a href="${entry.url}">${entry.name}</a></td></tr>`
    })
    html += '</table>'
    document.querySelector('body').innerHTML = html
  })
```

Comment: thank you for your response **@Mr5o1**
It fetches all the data from the given API but now I'm facing issues 'cause it's jquery statement and right now I'm not familiar with it. But once again thank you. But now I need specific details from AP like images, date, season, name, summary and rating, genres, country, not everything like I want to show 10 information on the page after the user clicks on load button next 10 more show information display on-page.

Comment: Sure no worries, this is actually vanilla js, no dependencies like jquery.